# Local flask/ flask container can connect to remote maria db, but Flask container on remote Ubuntu host can't

Tags: docker, flask, mariadb

### What I'm trying to do

I'm working on a flask API that is supposed to talk to a remote maria db.

### The problem

My local, non-containerized flask can connect to the remote mariadb no problem, as does the local Flask container, but I run into issues deploying it in a docker container on an remote ubuntu host. The container is building and responsive, but it can't connect to the mariadb.

Response when asking API to POST

```
<title>
    sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (mariadb.OperationalError) Can't connect to MySQL server on <mariadb_ip>; (115)
    (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8) // Werkzeug Debugger
</title>
```

All that changes from local Flask to remote Flask container is the remote Ubuntu host environment.

Here is my docker compose and dockerfile:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmariadb-dev

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV FLASK_APP=runner.py
ENV FLASK_ENV=production
ENV FLASK_DEBUG=0
ENV PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS=1
EXPOSE 5010

#COPY requirements.txt ./
#RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN pip install gunicorn
COPY . .


CMD ["gunicorn", "--reload", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5010", "runner:runner"]
```

docker-compose

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  api:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5010:5000"
```

### What I tried

A lot, but mostly figuring out if I set up Flask incorrectly and it doesn't seem the case. I then tried to focus on the dockerfile and if I overlooked something, but the the Flask API is building and responsive. I just can't figure out why it's working fine locally, but not remotely. I'm worried that it has something to do with the remote Ubuntu host, but I have no clue what that could be and how to resolve it.

Comment: first thing would be to check if the docker container can resolve mysql's host to an IP. not sure which tools your base image includes, i am usually using `curl` to see if its resolving hostnames to IPs. if this is the issue, one way to fix it is to inject a name in container's `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Did you create a db user that is allowed to connect from the container's IP to the remote db?